# Can you create a coupon code for collecting taxes only during checkout?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Is it possible, using native Magento functionality only, to use a coupon code that will reduce the grand total to a specific amount, and only charge them for taxes?

The use case is:

- Customer buys something on a 3rd party site for a reduced price.
- Let's say they pay $100 for a $200 product to use round numbers
- They don't pay taxes there
- They get a coupon code which they can use to redeem the purchase on our site
- When they checkout on our site, they may have to pay taxes

It's easy to create a coupon code for the $200 value, but the problem then is that the grand total on the order becomes $0 instead of $100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this cannot be done natively with cart rules.

Comment: Refactor: "this cannot be done with cart rule creation via the Magento admin".

Comment: ref. "natively" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The 'rule' engine in Magento, ***the underlying classes and architecture, can be tapped into todo this.*** With the creation of a custom rule class and by hooking it into the Magento system correctly, following the rule architecture, then you can apply whatever logic fits your promotion to the totals objects. You can even create your own totals object to handle the pricing adjustments and render in the totals grouping.

Comment: I was specifically looking for a native solution in this case.   I updated the question to be a bit more clear.